# execute scripts as cron in openshift docker

Tags: bash, docker, openshift

We are having a openshift environment where we need to backup data from some persistant volume source to destination everyday. I am thinking about setting up a container especially for this purpose and give the entry point as a bash script which does this copy action. How can I make sure that this script executes every day only once ? I can mention the sleep in script but that is not a good approach and would have effect if the POD restarts automatically in between. Please let me know the correct approach to do this ? I'm using OpenShift Web Console: v3.11.98

I can use sleep but not sure how to tackle the scenario where pod restarts

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e /source/]
then
        echo source /source is not mounted in the container
        exit 20
fi

if [ ! -e  /destination ]
then
        echo source /destination is not mounted in the container
        exit 20
fi

today1=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`


mkdir /destination/${today1}
cp -r /source/* /destination/${today1}
```

How can I run this script everyday to backup the fiels from one persistant volume to another. Any better way to do this other than running in a docker ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Kubernetes CronJob? This way the cluster will handle when to run it for you. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the Kubernetes [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) should solve this issue quite easily. This resource is also available on OpenShift.

Create your container which takes the backup . In this case the `/backup-script.sh` is the script which takes the backup.

The following YAML-file should create a cronjob in OpenShift:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup-job
spec:
  schedule: "* 23 * * *" 
  jobTemplate:            
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: backup-container-name
            image: PATH/TO/YOUR/BACKUP-CONTAINER
            command: ["/bin/sh", "/backup-script.sh"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

`spec.schedule` specifies how often the container should start. It follows the cron format here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

**NOTE:** You should double check the permissions needed to take the backup. If it requires privileged restrictions then you also have to add a `spec.jobTemplate.spec.serviceAccount` with a serviceAccount with the specified privileges.

A full YAML reference of this resource can be found here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/apis-batch/v2alpha1.CronJob.html

"restartPolicy" must be on the same level as "containers:". Otherwise it doesn´t work